# Entity Reference: User field not displaying unless user is referenced

Tags: entities

I have a field that references users: field_cc. When userA creates a node with this field populated with userB, userA cannot see the field when the node is displayed. If userA references himself, then userA will be able to see the field when the node is displayed.

This was on a clean install, no other permission-type module installed. Also tried fixing this with the Field Permissions module but this is did not help. I went through all possible permissions and settings but nothing seemed to work.

Am I misunderstanding how this module works out of the box?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does that field display a link to the user profile? I think it does, and your users do not have the 'View user profiles' permission, so they cannot see the link to a page they don't have access to.

Comment: That fixed it! It was that easy, huh?

Comment: All I did was give "Authenticated User" the permission to "View user profiles". The output was not a link, but I guess that doesn't matter in this context. Solution accepted!